# Cannot find an implementation class for grain interface

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, orleans

I have 2 interfaces in my assembly , and 2 grains that implement them.

```
public interface IGrain1:IGrainWithIntegerKey { void SomeMethod(); }
public interface IGrain2:IGrainWithIntegerKey { void SomeOtherMethod(); }

public Grain1:IGrain1
{
   public void SomeMethod()
   {
        var grain2=this.GrainFactory.GetGrain<IGrain2>([somekey]);
   }
}

public Grain2:IGrain2
{
       void SomeOtherMethod(){}
}
```

This call to grain of type `IGrain2` throws :

```
Cannot find an implementation class for grain interface: [path].IGrain2 . Make sure the grain assembly was correctly deployed and loaded in the silo.
```

I do not get why this exception happens , since both interfaces and grains are in the same assembly. Can anyone provide any idea ?

Comment: The answer to that question is almost certainly within `GrainFactory`, which isn't provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions for this case:

1. Adding MSBuild package reference:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Orleans.CodeGenerator.MSBuild" Version="3.4.2">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
 </PackageReference>
```

2. In your SiloBuilder in Startup you could use the `ConfigureApplicationParts` method to register the Assembly. This is not recommended but can be done like this:

```
siloBuilder.ConfigureApplicationParts((Action<IApplicationPartManager>)(parts =>
  {  
     parts.AddApplicationPart(typeof(SomeGrain).Assembly).WithReferences();
  }));
```

Comment: This is not valid anymore, since Orleans 7